# Jest tests don't run after update to Angular 15

Tags: angular, typescript, jestjs

After updating Typescript to 4.8 and Angular to 15 using ng update I find the next error message while trying to do a `ng test`:

```
● Validation Error:

Preset jest-preset-angular/presets/defaults-esm not found.
```

Does somebody have any clue on the matter? Thanks

Comment: Did you try to reinstall all of your packages?